# Which practise is better: v-show(true/false) or replaceWith? Vue vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I'm learning some vue.js right now and I was wondering which way should I go if, for example, I wanted to implement the following:
[image: Before clicking Edit button]

[image: After Edit button was clicked]

The question is, in HTML can I write `<span></span>` and bellow it add a `<textarea></textarea>` with `style="display: none"`, so on Edit button click, with some help of vue.js, I could hide span and show textarea instead, this way I wouldn't have to use jQuery's replaceWith method, plus I'd save some lines of code there. But I'm not sure if that's appropriate way to do it...

I'd also use v-cloak to hide textarea while page is still loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vue.js you would add a boolean to your component's `data` attributes like so:

```
data: {
   isEditing: false
}
```

Add an event handler to your edit button to set `isEditing` to `true` when the button is clicked with this directive:

```
<a href="#" @click="isEditing = true">...</a>
```

Finally add a `v-show` directive to your span so that it has the following attribute:

```
<span v-show="!isEditing">...</span>
```

This ensures that the span is visible when you are not in edit mode. We want to hide the span and instead show the textarea when we are editing, so you need to add another `v-show` on the textarea for when we are editing as below.

```
<textarea v-show="isEditing">...</textarea>
```

Using this approach requires no jQuery, although I am assuming that you are sending the form either via AJAX or a traditional POST, so I recommend the use of `v-show` in this case so that the form inputs are always within the DOM. `v-show` simply applies `display: none` to the element based on a condition rather than removing it entirely from the DOM as `v-if` would.

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right, I actually have already implemented that, but my question is whether it's a proper way to do it. You can see both html elements while inspecting the page, looks quite dirty, doesn't it? I would like to know which practise is better: this one with vue.js or using jquery's replaceWith method. Once again, for me, using vue.js the whole code looks more clear and kind a shorter.

Comment: @JakePery You can use `v-if` instead of `v-show`. `v-if` will not render DOM.

Comment: @JakePery Vue.js would be the more maintainable of the two, particularly if it is a sizeable project. If you refactored this into a component it also promotes reuse of code. I wouldn't worry about both HTML elements if you view source, although if that is your concern then by all means use `v-if` in place of `v-show`. The main motivator in my example for `v-show` is in case you need the form elements to be present within the DOM for form submission.

Comment: "I recommend the use of v-show in this case so that the form inputs are always within the DOM" - I'm using AJAX, can you tell me more about why I should use v-show instead of v-if here?

Comment: If you are using AJAX and you copy the values directly from inputs such as using jQuery to select the input and then copy the value `v-if` does not guarantee that it's in the DOM and available. This is because `v-if` will only render the input into the DOM if it's condition is satisfied. `v-if` might work in your use case, only if you submit the data when in edit mode. If you weren't in edit mode and submitted the data the textarea wouldn't be in the source, so you'd not have the data for the AJAX query, if that makes sense? Conversely v-show will always have the textarea in the source.

Answer (score 3):

It is almost always better to lean toward using Vue over jQuery if you are already using Vue, unless you are specifically writing a wrapper for a jQuery plugin.

It seems like your issue here is mainly that `v-show` is rendering to the DOM and hiding the rendered element. In Vue, you have two basic options for hiding content. `v-show` will render to the DOM, and use `display:none` to hide it. `v-if` will simply not render the element to the DOM.

So in your case you might want to do something like this:

```
<span v-if="showSpan">I'm a span!</span>
<textarea v-else></textarea>
```

This will render the span when `showSpan` is true, and the `textarea` when it is not.

For further explanation you can review the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

Comment: Thank you, that was my main concern. Didn't know that v-if wouldn't render  DOM. I really prefer vue.js way, I'll stick to that.